# Javascript function can't trigger onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function AjaxPost() {
 alert('asd');
});
</script>

<body>
<input name="btnUpdateUser" value="Update" id="btnUpdateUser" type="button" onclick="AjaxPost()" />
</body>
```

My problem it is not working. See live sample here: [CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pCyak)

But when I changed the onclick to this:

```
<input name="btnUpdateUser" value="Update" id="btnUpdateUser" type="button" onclick="javascript:alert('asd');" />
```

It is showing the alert. What did I missed here? Thanks!

Comment: I suppose AjaxPost doesn't exist. Try `var AjaxPost = function() { ... }; $(document).ready(AjaxPost);`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

it is because `AjaxPost` is not present in the global scope.

there is no need to use document ready in this case since the method is invoked by the user

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function AjaxPost() {
    alert('asd');
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this : call this function outside of `document`

```
function AjaxPost() {
   alert('asd');
}
```